# CSV not writing properly after scraping data for a website using Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am having problems writing a CSV file after scraping data from a website. My aim is to scrape a list of names and address of golf courses found in the United States. I used the `.get_text(separator=' ')` for the address to remove the `<Br>` to break-up the text for the address but when written to a CSV I only get three entries from my interactions of 893. What can I do so I get the right amount of scraped data and how can I fix my script so that it will properly scrape everything.

Here is my script:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

courses_list = []

for i in range(893): #893
    url="http://sites.garmin.com/clsearch/courses/search?course=&location=&country=US&state=&holes=&radius=&lang=en&search_submitted=1&per_page={}".format(i*20)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    g_data2 = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"result"})
    #print g_data

    for item in g_data2:
        try:
            name = item.find_all("div",{"class":"name"})[0].text
        except:
            name=''
            print "No Name found!"
        try:
            address= item.find_all("div",{"class":"location"})[0].get_text(separator=' ')
            print address
        except:
            address=''
            print "No Address found!"

course=[name,address]
courses_list.append(course)

with open ('Garmin_GC.csv','a') as file:
     writer=csv.writer(file)
     for row in courses_list:
         writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is your indentation then it is wrong, you need to add the name and address in the loop, this should add all the  data:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

courses_list = []
with open('Garmin_GC.csv', 'w') as file:
    for i in range(893):  #893
        url = "http://sites.garmin.com/clsearch/courses/search?course=&location=&country=US&state=&holes=&radius=&lang=en&search_submitted=1&per_page={}".format(
            i * 20)
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
        g_data2 = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "result"})
        for item in g_data2:
            try:
                name = item.find_all("div", {"class": "name"})[0].text
            except IndexError::
                name = ''
                print "No Name found!"
            try:

                address = item.find_all("div", {"class": "location"})[0].get_text(separator=' ')
                print address
            except IndexError::
                address = ''
                print "No Address found!"
            course = [name, address]
            courses_list.append(course)


    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for row in courses_list:
        writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])
```

You can open the file outside the loop and write once when you are finished, if you don't want to store all the data in the lists just write each iteration:

```
with open('Garmin_GC.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for i in range(3):  #893
        url = "http://sites.garmin.com/clsearch/courses/search?course=&location=&country=US&state=&holes=&radius=&lang=en&search_submitted=1&per_page={}".format(
            i * 20)
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
        g_data2 = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "result"})
        for item in g_data2:
            try:
                name = item.find_all("div", {"class": "name"})[0].text
            except IndexError:
                name = ''
                print "No Name found!"
            try:    
                address = item.find_all("div", {"class": "location"})[0].get_text(separator=' ')
                print address
            except IndexError:
                address = ''
                print "No Address found!"
            writer.writerow([name.encode("utf-8"), address.encode("utf-8")])
```

If you have no name or address then you may want to add a `continue` in the excepts if you want to ignore data that is missing either or both.